# How to achieve 'Facebook image tagging'-like functionality?

Tags: c#, wpf

Currently working on an app and I want to implement a feature where a user can click on a region of an image and type something (a description, or whatever) in that region. Similar to the Facebook image tagging feature in Facebook.

Unfortunately, I don't know how am I going to do that in C#/WPF.

Is there a control in WPF that I can use in order to achieve this functionality? Or how am I going to achieve it by doing it from scratch?

Comment: [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170823/Facebook-Style-Photo-Tag) might give you something to start with

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a special control for this. an idea for implementing this:

1. have the image fitted in a `Canvas` control. The canvas control helps you get the XY coordinates;
2. When clicking get the XY coordinates of the click;
3. Put a `Rectangle` (as a tag label) on XY coordinate that we've got later;
4. Store the the tag ID,  image ID, XY coordinates and the name of the tag, in the DB (or whatever datastorage you use);
5. When getting the image from the DB, get the tags of the image and repopulate the canvas.

Consider this as a pseoudo-code, you'll have to google how to get every step done.

Comment: Coments with the minus reason will be nice